# Prove the Jacobian Matrix (of a multi-variable function) is invertible

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

I'm trying to solve this question:
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function, i.e, its partial derivatives of first order exist and continuous. for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$: $\left \| f(x)-f(y)) \right \|> \frac{1}{10}\left \| x-y \right \|$.
I need to prove two things:

1. For all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $det(J(f))$, i.e., the Jacobian is invertible.
2. F is surjective: $f(\mathbb{R}^n) = \mathbb{R}^n$

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? Please edit your post to show some of your thoughts.

Comment: Item 2 is probably not trivial. Cf. global inverse theorem by Hadamard cited here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.07028.pdf or the result by Plastock: https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1974-200-00/S0002-9947-1974-0356122-6/S0002-9947-1974-0356122-6.pdf